# Docker+Laravel installation

Tags: php, bash, laravel, docker, centos

I use CentOS 7 for a little pjojekt with Docker and Laravel. Used a tutorial (https://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-centos/#) for the instalation and I dont dont know why but something gone wrong within the 5th Step. The terminal says this:

```
[root@docker laravel]# php artisan key:generate
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/laravel/artisan on line 31
```

And in the artisan line 31 is this:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

If someone has an idea the please help.
I want after installing Laravel combine Docker and Laravel with Laradock i hope this will not go wrong like this 
Thanks Moritz

Comment: Looks like you're using an old PHP version, as "class" constant is available from PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, for me it was a permission issue.

From the laravel docs(source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation):

Directory Permissions

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the  storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

So try changing the permissions on your host machine and see if it works.